# Check if property is defined in jena rules

Tags: jena, owl, jena-rules

In apache jena (*using rules*), how do I print when finding an instance that does **not** have a specified object property (*in a single rule*)?

Example (*print people without a job*):

`[ruleNoJob: (?p rdf:type :Person) ... -> print(?p, 'does not have a job')]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "noValue".  Example code below:

```
[ruleNoJob: (?p rdf:type :Person), noValue(?p aa:job) -> print(?p, 'does not have a job')]
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. I kept skimming through the list of Jena built-ins and completely missed the `noValue(...)` for some reason. Thanks.